# Update a field with display method

Tags: axapta, x++

I have a form with 2 fields, the 1st is filled with a lookup and the 2nd (not editable, just a Description of the 1st) is filled with a "display" method in the form.

```
public display Name displaySalesChannelName()
{
    return SalesChannelTable::find(SalesChannelFilter.valueStr()).Description;
}
```

Seems to work fine, but only shows the value when the field is clicked.

How can I synchronize this 2 fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override method `modified` of the 1st control (with the lookup) and call method `update` of the 2nd control from there, e.g. if the name of the 2nd control is SalesChannelName and its `AutoDeclaration` property has been set to *Yes*, then:

```
public boolean modified()
{
    boolean ret = super();

    SalesChannelName.update();

    return ret;
}
```

But then there's not much sense in using a display method here. You can just as well clear the `DataMethod` property of the 2nd control, and the `modified` method above can be rewritten as follows:

```
public boolean modified()
{
    boolean ret = super();

    SalesChannelName.text(SalesChannelTable::find(this.valueStr()).Description);

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try to put the display method on table level, your field's properties in the form must have the datasource Table name as datasource and your method's name as data method